# UISwitch sometime fail to trigger value Change Event

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8, uiswitch, ios8.1

When I drag a UISwitch slowly, i have observed that sometimes(not always) both touch inside and value change Event does not get fired and UiSwitch State got change. But when tapped, value change Event is executed. I have observed this issue on both iOS7 and iOS8 when UISwitch is dragged.

Comment: So the question is...? If you think this is a real issue, just [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/logon)